# undefined reference to `__kmalloc'

Tags: c, linux-kernel, ld

While compiling code that uses the SCTP kernel header `<sctp/chunk.h>`I got a puzzling compiler error(with blue text instead of read) that was trigged by the calling of the `kmalloc` function whose prototype is defined in `<linux/slob-def.h>`. Here is the function that caused it:

```
/* Allocate and initialize datamsg. */
SCTP_STATIC struct sctp_datamsg *sctp_datamsg_new(gfp_t gfp)
{
    struct sctp_datamsg *msg;
    msg = kmalloc(sizeof(struct sctp_datamsg), gfp);
    if (msg) {
        sctp_datamsg_init(msg);
        SCTP_DBG_OBJCNT_INC(datamsg);
    }
    return msg;
}
```

The gcc error message(compiling in native C):

```
/tmp/ccKDKVjf.o: In function `sctp_datamsg_new':
s.c:(.text+0x2215): undefined reference to `__kmalloc'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So what I'm wondering is if the `kmalloc` function source code properly defined(or not actually implemented at all, or if code that calls this function can only be compiled in kernel mode. I was not actually trying to build an output file(yet), the compile command I issued in Emacs was: `gcc s.c` (where `s.c` is the `.c` file that contains the `<sctp/chunk.h>` header — just trying to make sure everything compiles properly before building an output file).

Answer (score 1):

That's a linker error, the code compiled fine. Next time, specify `-c` to avoid linking.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, does that mean that the kmalloc source code is absent? If so then I am missing a library file and will have to download it.

Comment: The `kmalloc` source code is already compiled into the kernel, there's nothing else that needs to be done to or with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to build kernel source without including kernel headers and linking against other kernel modules and the kernel itself, you are going to get errors.

You cannot just use gcc to build kernel source code. There is a way to build them.

Comment: Vivek, I am compiling(& linking)but not building. Once everything compiles correctly then I will build the actual source code.

Comment: What is the difference between compiling + linking and building ? If you do not link with the kernel and include kernel headers, you won't be able to compile your source code.

Comment: Perhaps I need to download the Kernel source and that is what is causing this link error.

Comment: Vivek: I've got that book. So I'll read up on Chapter 2. But clearly there IS missing kernel source code because that's what causes a link error.

Comment: @Mr X You can either download the latest kernel, build it first, then build your code by providing the path to this downloaded and built kernel or Build against the kernel already installed on your system.